# Gradle error - Failed to resolve adding TomTom Maps SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I want to calculate distance between 2 points and show the distance and duration in a textview. For that I am using TomTom's Rounting API. When I am trying to add the dependancy to my project, my gradle is throwing the following error - 
**ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.tomtom.online:sdk-routing:2.4101
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app**

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the TomTom Documentation - https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-android-sdk/getting-started-2

These are the code changes that I have made -

Added compileOptions in the app build.gradle file -

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
        applicationId "com.example.practiseRouting"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Added dependencies as well

```
implementation 'com.tomtom.online:sdk-routing:2.4101'
```

Added the API Key in Manifest file -

```
<meta-data
                android:name="OnlineRouting.Key"
                android:value="--------------------------------" />
```

I have a stable internet connection so that should not be an issue. Any help in resolving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you replace `2.4101` in your dependencies with a `+` ?

Comment: @payam,replacing ```2.4101``` with a ```+``` did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-android/android-tutorials-use-cases/search-along-route

In the build.gradle project file, add the TomTom repository to the list of repositories. The TomTom Maps SDK dependencies are downloaded from there.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.tomtom.com:8443/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also giving me the same error. Failed to resolve the dependency.

Comment: No, actually that was my mistake. I was adding the url at the wrong place. Its working for me now. Thank you.